# Gitlab Build Design: Tests from local image?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I’m working on a build pipeline using docker-in-docker (through a `docker:20.10-dind` service) that should:

- build a docker image from a base image + plugin files
- run unit and integration tests using that image (requiring a mariadb service, so I’d like to cleanly separate that out into a test phase)
- then publish the image by pushing it to the registry if the tests were successful

During build I tag the image as all of:

- name:latest
- registry/projectid/name:latest
- registry/projectid/name:base-image-version

In the test phase I tell it to use `image: name:latest` tag (i.e. without remote registry information) as the image for running the job.

I expected it to use the image existing in the local D-in-D service, but it doesn’t, & I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): failed to pull image "name:latest" with specified policies [always]: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for name, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login' (manager.go:205:0s)
```

**Is there any way to change the pull policy only for one pipeline, or even better only for one phase/job in a pipeline?**

The only place I could find was `config.toml` for a whole build runner, which is really not the granularity I am looking for.

If it’s absolutely not possible, I could tag the image as `registry/project/name:candidate` in build and push it + then pull it again for test.

That would however occasionally leave broken images lying around, and would also be extremely wasteful and make my build much slower, so I’d really prefer not to pull an image that has to already exist in the docker service for the build.

Comment: Huge discussion is here: [Caching for docker-in-docker builds](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/17861#note_187018544) (direct link to one of comments with workaround). The main idea is: `/var/lib/docker` is a temporary volume for one run, this is by design.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, the answer is no.

The only way is to tag the image and push it to the registry and then pull it again for the tests.

After the tests you can delete this very tag from the registry. Or you set up a cleanup policy which removes these tags occasionally.

Comment: i ended up “fixing” it by having build & test in one phase, since I don’t need to push broken images anyway